# Transition in Android navigation between fragments

Tags: android, android-animation, android-navigation

I know that there are two possibilities to add animation to any Android destination:

- Using graph, I can add manually animation file on enter/exit.
- Using Kotlin/Java with `NavOptions` and passing to `navigate()`.

But I know also there are `Transitions` like `Explode` to animate a changing Activity.

How can I convert `Transition` to `Animation` and use it to animate changing Fragments? Is there a possibility to inject `Explode` transition to Navigation?

Comment: The [Fragment Transition APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#set-transitions) work whether you are using the Navigation Component or not. Is there a reason you aren't using the Fragment APIs directly?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I was reading Navigation spec, but not actually Fragment spec. It works. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Like **ianhanniballake** said, I should read `Fragment` documentation, not `Navigation`. I just added in my `Fragment` class:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val inflater = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext())
        val transition = android.R.transition.explode
        enterTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(transition)
        exitTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(transition)
    }
```

and it works like a charm.